# If I were to win the election, I would restore the vitality of downtown area

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

**If I were to win the election, I would restore the vitality of downtown area.**

In the above sentence, I understand that it's a hypothetical situation so it comes with "I were" and "I would". However, I don't understand the use of "were to". What is the intended meaning of "were to" here.

Comment: Please also visit [ell.se]

Answer (score 0):

*Were to win* in this context is subjunctive, and indicates that winning the election is a hypothetical situation. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Compound_forms.2C_auxiliaries_and_modals) on the subjunctive in English.

*Were to* on its own doesn't mean anything; *to win* is simply the infinitive.